# How to find all macOS applications which are not from the App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

How do I find all of the Applications on my Mac which are *not* from the App Store? Is it possible to find all those applications using a [Finder search query](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21873?locale=en_US)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The screenshot below shows how to use a Finder search query to find all applications that are not from the App Store. The “Raw Query” condition is `kMDItemAppStoreHasReceipt != 1`. This is the same, I think, as testing for a directory named “_MASReceipt” as in the answer by patrix. But using a Finder search query should be easier for people not comfortable with using Terminal.

[image: Screenshot of Finder Search Query for Applications not from App Store]

Comment: Here are a few addenda to my answer. To run the same query in Terminal use: `mdfind 'kMDItemContentType == "com.apple.application-bundle" && kMDItemAppStoreHasReceipt != 1'`. To find the applications that *do* come from the App Store, change the `!= 1` check to `== 1`. There are some other Spotlight attributes related to the App Store, to check their values for Keynote for example: `mdls /Applications/Keynote.app | grep kMDItemAppStore`.

Comment: Another addendum. I’ve found it useful to add another “Raw Query” condition: `kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier != "com.apple.*"`. This filters out Apple-applications, like the various applications that do not come from the App Store but are part of macOS (Mail, Safari, iTunes and so on).

Answer (score 11):

- Applications from the store are installed in `/Applications` (at least by default), so any applications outside of that folder are not from the store.
- Applications from the store have a `NAME.app/Contents/_MASReceipt` folder, so you could use (in Terminal)

  ```
  cd /Applications
  for i in *.app; do
      [[ -d "$i/Contents/_MASReceipt" ]] || echo $i
  done
  ```

  to find all non-store applications

Comment: Just wanted to add: This is bash.

Comment: @MaxRied Thanks for pointing this out. As `bash` is the default in Terminal I usually assume that anybody experienced enough to switch shells also is experienced enough to adapt bash-specific stuff to their shell of choice. Or use `[ ... ]` instead of `[[ ... ]]`

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to go to the Apple Menu -> "About this Mac...", then click "System Report". In the window that shows up, you can scroll to the Software section, and click "Applications".  Apps from the Mac App Store are listed as such.

In the screen shot, Skitch was downloaded from the Mac App Store.[image: Sample screen shot]